# How to access Game state on Google Cloud with Facebook ID?

Tags: facebook, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am trying to access game state from Google server of a Facebook friend. I fetch the List of Facebook friends from Facebook SDK and get a Facebook-id of a friend in return. Game state is present on Google server against Google-id. How can I form a mapping between these two? I want to achieve this without  involving any other server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dTo get this right you need involving other server.
Although you can do is create a list in a local file, with the relation google user - Id facebook

Comment: Agreed, another server involvement is necessary. I was looking for a built-in capability in either google-play or Facebook SDK. But Thanks anyway.